# What am I doing wrong with this "create an Aura Component" trailblazer tutorial?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, trailhead

I am playing around with this trailblazer tutorial:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/quickstart-lightning-components/quickstart-lightning-components3
but when I try to save their example (step 6), it gives me this error:

[image: image of popup error]

text of error:

```
FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION: Failed to save MyContactList.cmp: Invalid definition for null:MyContactListController: ApexService.getType() return null with currentNamespace: c, namespace: null, name: MyContactListController: Source
```

<s>I suspect that the issue here is that the tutorial example used to be right when it was originally written, but that something changed in a subsequent salesforce quarterly update that broke it, seeing that I just copied the code over from the example:</s>

**Update: I didn't pay close enough attention to the tutorial I landed on from a google search. It was step 2 in a multi-step tutorial and I hadn't done step 1 yet.**

```
<aura:component controller="MyContactListController" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
<aura:attribute name="Account" type="Account" />
<aura:attribute name="Contacts" type="Contact" />
<aura:attribute name="Columns" type="List" />
<force:recordData aura:id="accountRecord"
                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                  targetFields="{!v.Account}"
                  layoutType="FULL"
                  />
<lightning:card iconName="standard:contact" title="{! 'Contact List for ' + v.Account.Name}">
    <!-- Contact list goes here -->
</lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

Has anyone seen this issue as well? Is there a workaround so that I can keep playing with this trailblazer tutorial?

Comment: I hope you have the apex class already created as described in the earlier step?

Comment: @JayantDas That was it. I got to the trailblazer tutorial from a google search and I didn't look close enough to realize I was on step 2 of the tutorial. I should have noticed that. <embarrassed>

Comment: @JayantDas, thank you for figuring it out though. I'm happy to award your assessment as the answer if you would want to put it down as your answer to my question.

Comment: Actually you may like to answer it yourself and mark as answered, I just gave a clue but you definitely figured it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't pay close enough attention to the tutorial I landed on from a google search. It was step 2 in a multi-step tutorial and I hadn't done step 1 yet.

If you find yourself in a similar situation, please do better than I did here and double-check that you have done all the previous steps in the trailblazer tutorial.